# How to split regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have problem to split this variable. I just want the `1088` number.

```
http://ebook.com/php+in+100+days-1088.aspx
```

I've tried, but no luck, my code

```
print_r(preg_split("/[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+.aspx/", 'http://ebook.com/php+in+100+days-1088.aspx'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match( '/(\d+)\.aspx$/', 'http://ebook.com/php+in+100+days-1088.aspx', $matches );
```

$matches[1] gives you the 1088 number.

Comment: +1 for including the .aspx in regex. other suggestions may fail with certain URLs such as `ebook.com/php.in+1000-days-1088.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why the regex, but this one works for me:

```
$parts = preg_split("/(-|\.)/", 'http://ebook.com/php+in+100+days-1088.aspx');
echo $parts[2];
```